# iis 7 log missing for some sites

Tags: asp.net, iis, iis-logs

We use IIS 7.
We have log enabled to be daily for all our sites. For new sites, I can see logs are created properly, but for old sites, the logs are just not there. From IIS manager, I can see the log is enabled, but for some reason, the logging stopped like one month ago.

We installed debugdiag on this server, will this software somehow hide or redirect iis log? Is there any register key I can check (other than what I can see from IIS manager)?

Many Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like an NTFS permissions issue with the target logs folder.

When restarting IIS, you will see entries in Event Viewer stating it could not create the log file.

See [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/625975/iis-log-folder-permissions-not-being-inherited) and check your folder permissions.